# PHP: Get newly generated pdf in "save as.." popup

Tags: php, pdf

```
<form  method="POST" action="createPDF.php">
<input type="text" id="myID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userSession']?>" style="display:none"/>
<input type="submit" value="showPDF"/>
</form>
```

I am sending `myID` variable to `createPDF.php` page and generating pdf file. I am using TCPDF library for pdf files.
My createPDF.php code:

```
$myFile=$pdf->Output('mypdf001.pdf', 'I');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .$myFile);
```

I am getting save as popup with `.php` file or am being redirected to createPDF.php file. How to get save as pop up with .pdf file?

Comment: I don't quite get the last sentence. Could you rephrase? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: After i push showPDF submit button,  I need "Save as" popup window, in order to save my generated pdf file

Comment: I don't think that is possible, as that is a browser setting: either "Save as", or "open in the browser", or "open in another application". You cannot force a choice from your page.

Comment: I think its possible, but am getting save as .php file, not my generated pdf

Comment: Your use of the `Content-Disposition` header is OK, do you have the right content type set?

Comment: `$pdf->Output('myPDF001.pdf', 'I');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myPDF001.pdf');` This way am being redirected to createPDF.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your PHP configuration allows, you could try changing your form to

```
<form  method="POST" action="createPDF.php/myPDF001.pdf">
```

If your PHP configuration allows it, this will still run the createPDF.php file, but the browsers will be more likely to see it as a PDF file.

Also ensure that the content-type header is correctly set

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
```

Finally (although I'm not 100% sure if this makes a difference) set the headers before outputting the PDF

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the content type before the content-disposition?

I think you are missing:

```
header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

So you would have:

```
$myFile=$pdf->Output('mypdf001.pdf', 'I');  
header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .$myFile);
```